# Is smartd properly configured to send alerts by email?

Tags: smart, smartctl

I just configured a Debian server as follows
apt-get install smartmontools
vi /etc/default/smartmontools - and here uncommented these 2 lines
`# uncomment to start smartd on system startup`
`start_smartd=yes`
`# uncomment to pass additional options to smartd on startup`
`smartd_opts="--interval=1800"`

Then I edited /etc/smartd.conf and uncommented only this line
`DEVICESCAN -S on -o on -a -m myemail@mydomain.com -s (S/../.././02|L/../../6/03)`

I was wondering if this is enough for the system to send me an alert message when something goes wrong and/or if there is a way to simulate a problem and see if smartd sends me warnings by email.

Comment: Really you should configure the alias for `root` in /etc/aliases (if using postfix) so that any server generated emails are forwarded to your email account, not just smartd.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can test the configuration by adding `-M test` to the line that begins with `DEVICESCAN`, immediately after that keyword. The next time you restart smartd, it will send out an email notification.

Comment: I found that the -M option has to be immediately after DEVICESCAN, not at the end.  This works:
`DEVICESCAN -M test -H -s S/../../7/02  -m me@email.com`
but this doesn't (illegal -M Directiive: test):
`DEVICESCAN -H -s S/../../7/02  -m me@email.com -M test`

Comment: `-M test` at the end of the `DEVICESCAN` works ok on Debian Jessie / `smartctl 6.6`