# Disk Monitoring with cronjobs -- report disk issues

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, hard-drive, diskmanagement

Is there a way to monitor disk health and send cronjob reports for errors?

I know you can use `smartctl -s on -a /dev/hda` to pull information but just wondering if there is a way that could be used to filter and only send if something needs attention.

Is SmartMon something I want to look into?

Comment: You can write a script that wraps `smartctl` and only generates output when something needs attention...

Comment: related post - http://serverfault.com/questions/426761/is-smartd-properly-configured-to-send-alerts-by-email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up `smartd` to run as a daemon and email you when a disk error occurs. Add `-m your@email.com` to the relevant line of the `smartd` configuration file (e.g. `/etc/smartd.conf` or `/etc/default/smartmontools`). This is the line that usually begins with `DEVICESCAN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run smartd as a service by enabling it in the smartd config file, /etc/smartd.conf for RHEL for instance. There is an option for sending an alert message when something goes wrong.